# Rsession.exe not releasing RAM

Tags: r

Running R program that requires a lot of RAM (Running in R studio).   After program finishes running, rsession.exe is not releasing the ram.  I have to close and restart R in order to release the RAM.  I have tried using gc() garbage collection but it does not fix the problem.  Any suggestions on ways to periodically free up the RAM without restarting would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: The `gc` command is really only useful after removing an object from the environment, which can be done with `rm`. Does using `rm(list = ls())` do what you're looking for?

Comment: Personally, I use R Studio and restart R (menu Session \ Restart R) pretty often and I see no problem with that.

Comment: Unfortunately rm(list=ls()) does not have the desired effect.  If I am using Rstudio rsession.exe uses all the RAM, in base R I get the same problem with Rgui.  Neither will release without closing R entirely.  I think it may be caused by the .RDataTmp folder created by the program.

Comment: This is on Windows OS, right? If so, the easiest solution I have found to get R to release the memory rapidly back to teh OS, is to change the priority of R to "high" or "realtime". This can be changed from the Task Manager by right clicking on the relevant process / program name, and then selecting "Set Priority". Would that work for you?

Comment: I tried that a few different ways to no avail.  Task manager will not allow me to set it to realtime but it will set to high fine.  Still is not releasing the RAM however.